# Can you export the counter in a job as a CSV?

Tags: powershell

I am running the following code to run a `perfmon` counter, but am unable to run `Export-Counter -Path $DestinationFile -FileFormat csv` on its `Receive-Job` output.

```
Start-Job -Name GettingCounters -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 120
}
$i = 0 
$duration = 120 
while ((Get-Job GettingCounters).State -eq 'Running') {
    #increment
    $i++ 

    #Round the numbers up for a nice output and then Write-Progress
    Write-Progress -Activity "Processing $user" -PercentComplete (($i/$duration)*100) -Status ("Gathering data...")
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about not using 'Export-Counter' but 'Export-Csv'

```
Start-Job -Name GettingCounters -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Counter -Counter "\Processor(_total)\% Processor Time" -SampleInterval 1 -MaxSamples 3
}

while ((Get-Job GettingCounters).State -eq 'Running') {
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 
}

$job = Get-Job GettingCounters |Receive-Job 

# better Format-Table?
$job |Select-Object PSComputerName, Timestamp, @{Label='Readings'; Expression={$_.Readings.trim()}} |Export-Csv -Path test

# lousy cleaning
Get-Job |Remove-Job
```

or alternatively, if you don't have to run it remotely, not using a job?

working with remote "objects" seems a bit tricky to me

> However, the deserialized object is not a live object. It is a snapshot of 
>       the object at the time that it was serialized, and it includes properties 
>       but no methods. You can use and manage these objects in Windows PowerShell,
>       including passing them in pipelines, displaying selected properties, and 
>       formatting them.

[about_Remote_Output](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847891.aspx)